# Functions Method, student mark

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x, y;

    System.out.println("Student 1 please enter your mark: ");
    x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Student 2 please enter your mark: ");
    y = sc.nextInt();
}

public static int marks(int x, int y) {
    valid = 1;
    if(x > 100 || y > 100) {
        System.out.println("Invalid mark!! the marks has to be between 0-100");
    } else if(x < y) {
        System.out.println("Student 2 has higher mark than Student 1");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Student 1 has higher mark than Student 2");
    }
    return valid;
}
```

My code works fine, but I have to put it in a procedure method. I don't know how to do that because there are two students. Do I have to make three signatures?

Comment: What is your code trying to do? Why do you want to put in a method? What should this method do?

Comment: Bably, ALWAYS give people indented code. As a rule, I don't even look at unindented code. It is not readable. Trust me, get used to it now - don't get into the habit of giving code that isn't indented properly.

Comment: Where do you declare `valid`? And you never call the method `marks` in the main method

Comment: It CAN be called in the main method, you just aren't currently calling it. After the second `sc.nextInt()`, you need to call `marks(x, y);`

Comment: Press Control + Shift + f if you are using eclipse to indent your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `valid` variable . Rename `marks` to `compareMarks` and change its return type to void . The naming convention says that methods names should be verbs . Finally just call the method in main . Try to indenting your code well. It makes it more readable

```
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
       Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
       int x, y ;

       System.out.println("Student 1 please enter your mark: ");
       x= sc.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Student 2 please enter your mark: ");
       y=sc.nextInt();

       compareMarks (x, y);
    }

    public static void compareMarks (int x, int y)
    {
      if (x>100 || y>100)
      {
         System.out.println("Invalid mark!! the marks has to be between 0-100");
      }
      else if (x<y)
      {
         System.out.println("Student 2 has higher mark than Student 1");
      }
      else 
      {
         System.out.println("Student 1 has higher mark than Student 2");
      }
   }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of it. You are not changing it anywhere in the method . Its like saying return 1.

Comment: Try and understand the method signature. int and void are return types of the method. If you are not returning anything then th etype should be void Refer to this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: you are right!! Your method does not need to return anything because it is computing the result and printing the output itself

Comment: those are the parameters you pass to the method. Since you want to compare marks of two students

Comment: You do not need reputation to ask questions. Only those questions that add value to the forum are candidates for upvotes